# Embed Facebook Event Feed on Website

Tags: facebook, web, embed, feed, squarespace

I've found a few really old answers that do not work.  I am building a website for my church.    What I want to do is have a feed that shows events from Facebook, that way when the lady that does our social media adds an event it will automatically post them to our website.  This will keep the website easy to maintain.  Besides paying for a plugin, what is the best way to go about this?

**Yes, I know you can embed events.**  But I am trying to keep it as easy as possible for people at my church who are not really techie or know how to design websites.  Please help.

I am using squarespace and the website is ccodtruth.org

Comment: The Page plugin, configured to show the events tab, would be the easiest way to achieve this. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/ If you want more than what that offers, then you will have to familiarize yourself with the API, so that you can read the event data from the Facebook page, and then display it yourself within your system.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried the page plugin.  It's pretty much useless for what I want because it's so small.  Thanks for the suggestion. Maybe someone else has another?

Comment: I can't believe this is still unanswered.  I'm trying to do the same thing and it's proving a challenge.  You can set up your website to allow a user to login to their own facebook page and you can embed their stuff, but I want to add a single business' facebook page events to the site.  I don't want the user to log in, I don't want to display any feeds or contacts, I don't need a like button.  I just want a list of events with links to the event.  How hard is this?  apparently, hard....

Comment: @BrianVPS I'm going through the same thing right now. Now all APIs want you to authenticate because they tie up their GET calls for publicly available data with data with POST calls to add stuff to facebook. In our case we just want the events. My theory on this: Facebook wants users to go to their site. Or it's just they only support app devs and people who make websites are a rare breed and they don't care.